# A tricky javascript question

Tags: javascript, serialization, functional-programming, scope

I'll probably best explain this through code. I got something like this:

```
var object1 = function(){ 
  //do something 
}
var object2 = function(){
  //do something else
}

var objects = {
  'o1' : object1,
  'o2' : object2  
};

var actions = [];

function addAction( actionName ){
 var object = objects[actionName];
 actions.push( function(){ new object(); } );
}
```

So this code, saves a sequence of runtime-determined actions based on user input that are saved in an array.

```
addAction( "o1" );
addAction( "o2" );
```

If I want to replay that sequence I just do:

```
for( i in actions ){
  actions[i]();
}
```

and this will create two anonymous objects of type object1 and object2.

Now, I need somehow to serialize the actions[] array but I need each of the functions within it to retain it's scope. If I just cast the functions to strings I get:

```
"function(){ new object(); }"
```

and if I eval this string, then 'object' would be undefined. How would you do this ?

Answer (score 5):

Why not keep the name of the action along with the function in an object, so that you can use that for serialisation:

```
function Action(name, func) {
   this.name = name;
   this.func = objects[name];
}

function addAction(actionName) {
   actions.push(new Action(actionName));
}
```

The code to run the functions would change slightly:

```
for (i in actions) actions[i].func();
```

To serialise the array you would just put the names in a string:

```
var s = '';
for (i in actions) {
   s += (s.length == 0 ? '' : ',') + actions[i].name;
}
```

Then to deserialise you just recreate the objects from the names:

```
var names = s.split(',');
for (i in names) {
   addAction(new Action(names[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to serialize your list of actions for playback later, you should modify your addAction function to just store the name of the action.

```
function addAction(actionName)
{
    actions.push(actionName);
}
```

And when you go to play back, you'd use

```
for(i in actions)
{
    objects[actions[i]]();
}
```

Since your action list is just strings, you should have no problem with the serialization.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit unclear on what scope you expect the function to have.

Simply pushing the function in

```
actions.push(objects[actionName]);
```

may have the effect you want...